# What causes a different namespace prefix in XML from the server

Tags: node.js, xml, server, response

I am working with an application called Teamcenter. What we have noticed is for some API requests, the namespace in the XML response is coming up without any namespace (<AsmlUpdateGLOutputs response).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><AsmlUpdateGLOutputs response="Request cannot be processed:User abc does not exist in Teamcenter. Please do check the input UserId." status="" xmlns="http://a5oa.com/Schemas/BotOps/2018-11/ASMLBotOps" xmlns:ns2="http://teamcenter.com/Schemas/Soa/2006-03/Base"/></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

For other requests to the same API, I get a namespace prefix ns2 (<ns2:AsmlUpdateGLOutputs response=).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><ns2:AsmlUpdateGLOutputs response=" Request can not be processed as you are already present in the GL List, please do check by restarting Teamcenter, If problem still persist please do contact ASML IT HELPDESK or drop a mail at &lt;asmlitg@service-now.com&gt; for further Support." status="" xmlns="http://teamcenter.com/Schemas/Soa/2006-03/Base" xmlns:ns2="http://a5oa.com/Schemas/BotOps/2018-11/ASMLBotOps"/></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

We had a product upgrade and now wee see an altogether new namespace, ns3 ( xmlns:ns3 ) having ns2 ( xmlns:ns2 ).

```
"xmlns:ns3":"http://a5oa.com/Schemas/BotOps/2018-11/ASMLBotOps","xmlns:ns2":"http://teamcenter.com/Schemas/Soa/2006-03/Base","canProcessCurrentRequestedService":"true","requestingServiceForSelf":"true","requestingUserIsAdmin":"false","response":"","asmlTeamcenterUserIDCorrespondingSharepointEmail":"","errorMessage":"","doPassedSharepointEmailIDUniqueInTc":"false","doDuplicateEmailAddressExistInTeamcenter":"false","doUserExistWithSharepointEmailIDInTeamcenter":"false","asmlReqUserLocation":"0"
```

Why does this happen - is this some expected design in the industry?.

Comment: Just vendor behind the Teamcenter app. can answer your question.

Comment: Weell the last output you post looks more like json? ns2 and ns3 are usually autogenerated namespace names when you create an xml export with a schema xsd and leave out the target namespaces.

Comment: Namespace prefixes only matter in their binding to namespace values.  Any software that depends on actual namespace prefixes is broken, probably because it tries, but fails, to parse XML itself rather than using an established parsing library.